# Compatibility of partial_transpose in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, density-matrix

I need to calculate the negativity of a density matrix; in doing so on Qiskit I stuck on the problem of computing the partial transpose for a problem of compatibility.

Basically I extract my density matrix from a circuit via the Aer simulator in the following way:

```
circuit.append(SaveDensityMatrix(size, label = f'pho_%.1f' % (label)), [i for i in qubits])

aer_sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
t_qc = transpile(circuit, aer_sim)
qobj = assemble(t_qc)
results = aer_sim.run(qobj, shots = 1).result()
counts = results.get_counts()

density_matrix = results.data()['pho_%.1f' % (i)]
```

the object resulting from this has the type :

```
qiskit_aer.backends.compatibility.DensityMatrix
```

How can I use the method `partial_transpose` described here as `qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.partial_transpose`?

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.partial_transpose.html

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the negativity measure of a density matrix, there is a function for this in the [toqito](https://github.com/vprusso/toqito) quantum information package [here](https://toqito.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/toqito.state_props.negativity.html). It accepts a numpy array of the density matrix, so this is compatible with your Qiskit code (you can cast the rho as a numpy array). The source code also contains the implementation for how to compute the partial transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the subsystems to be transposed are the first two qubits, that is, qubits with indexes 0 and 1. Then you can simply get the partially transposed density matrix as follows:

```
rho = density_matrix.partial_transpose([0, 1])

# Display rho:
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(rho)
```